# Hide key value pair based on boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Stripe to charge my users for coaching services. Currently, a coach can decide what plans he wants to offer in his settings.

If a coach only has basic_coaching set to `false` then that is the only Stripe button that should **not** appear.

How would I go about that?

Here is my schema:

```
t.boolean "basic_coaching", default: true
t.boolean "professional_coaching", default: true
t.boolean "premium_coaching", default: true
t.boolean "platinum_coaching", default: true
```

Here is my controller:

```
@usd_plans = { # Plan ID -> Description
  'basic_usd': 'Basic Coaching',
  'professional_usd': 'Professional Coaching',
  'premium_usd': 'Premium Coaching',
  'platinum_usd': 'Platinum Coaching'
}
```

Here is my view:

```
- @usd_plans.each do |plan_id, description|
  td
    = form_tag(subscriptions_path) do
      = hidden_field_tag 'plan', plan_id
      = hidden_field_tag 'coach_id', @user.id
      = hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id
      = hidden_field_tag 'description', description
      - if current_user.coupon_code
        = hidden_field_tag 'coupon_code', current_user.coupon_code

      script.stripe-button(
        src='https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js'
        data-key=Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]
        data-name="#{@user.name}"
        data-description=description
        data-image="#{@user.avatar.url}"
        data-locale='auto'
        data-panel-label='Subscribe now'
        data-label='Buy'
        data-allow-remember-me='false'
        data-email=current_user.email
    )
```

Here is what it looks like with all 4 booleans set to `true`. Ideally, I would just hide a button, if that specific boolean is set to `false`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment on @mrzasa's good answer, I'd suggest you might need to handle the logic in your view, so can add a placeholder if the plan button isn't required.

Something like:

Keep `@usd_plans` as is:

```
@usd_plans = { # Plan ID -> Description
               'basic_usd': 'Basic Coaching',
               'professional_usd': 'Professional Coaching',
               'premium_usd': 'Premium Coaching',
               'platinum_usd': 'Platinum Coaching }
```

Then in your view:

```
- @usd_plans.each do |plan_id, description|
  td
    - if @user.try(description.underscore) # or description.downcase.split(' ').join('_'), I haven't got Rails handy to test `underscore`
      = form_tag(subscriptions_path) do
        = hidden_field_tag 'plan', plan_id
        = hidden_field_tag 'coach_id', @user.id
        = hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id
        = hidden_field_tag 'description', description
        - if current_user.coupon_code
          = hidden_field_tag 'coupon_code', current_user.coupon_code

        script.stripe-button(
          src='https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js'
          data-key=Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]
          data-name="#{@user.name}"
          data-description=description
          data-image="#{@user.avatar.url}"
          data-locale='auto'
          data-panel-label='Subscribe now'
          data-label='Buy'
          data-allow-remember-me='false'
          data-email=current_user.email
        )
```

This way, crucially, the `td` tag will be inserted regardless, while the button only plugged in if the user has that attribute set.

Give it a try and let me know how you get on - happy to help with any questions.

Comment: Excellent suggestion as well SRack. I'm going to accept this as the answer because it achieves what I wanted to in one line even with a very poorly articulated question. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @Andy. Let me know if you've any other questions!

Answer (score 3):

You can decide the when you build `@usd_plans`, e.g. something like:

```
@usd_plans = {}.tap do |plans| # Plan ID -> Description
  plans['basic_usd'] =  'Basic Coaching' if coach.basic_coaching?
  plans['professional_usd'] =  'Professional Coaching' if coach.professional_coaching?
  plans['premium_usd'] =  'Premium Coaching' if coach.premium_coaching?
  plans['platinum_usd'] =  'Platinum Coaching' if coach.platinum_coaching?
end
```

You can of course make it more DRY with some string concatenation and metaprogramming. The repetitive version is better for understanding :).

**EDIT:** If you want to keep the layout, try to hide it in the view

```
@usd_plans = {}.tap do |plans| # Plan ID -> Description
  plans['basic_usd'] =  {name: 'Basic Coaching', visible: coach.basic_coaching? }
  # etc...
end

- @usd_plans.each do |plan_id, data|
  td
    next unless data[:visible]
    = form_tag(subscriptions_path) do
      = hidden_field_tag 'plan', data[:plan_id]
      = hidden_field_tag 'coach_id', @user.id
      = hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.id
      = hidden_field_tag 'description', description
      - if current_user.coupon_code
        = hidden_field_tag 'coupon_code', current_user.coupon_code

      script.stripe-button(
        src='https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js'
        data-key=Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]
        data-name="#{@user.name}"
        data-description=description
        data-image="#{@user.avatar.url}"
        data-locale='auto'
        data-panel-label='Subscribe now'
        data-label='Buy'
        data-allow-remember-me='false'
        data-email=current_user.email
    )
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion and it works like a charm. The issue with this solution is that my Stripe buttons move. In this case, I made 'basic_coaching' == `false` and this was the result: https://imgur.com/a/goFh9

Comment: Thanks for your help @mrzasa. Very much appreciated.